# Mysql working remotely but not localy

Tags: networking, mysql, cloud

I have a cloud based application in PHP with one master server and multiple slaves. All servers are using master's database (mysql).

I already done this steps

```
CREATE USER 'mysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_secret_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysql'@'%';
```

Also I commented "skip-external-locking" and "bind-address" from my.cnf

The connection from my Mac works and it also works from each slave server.
On the master server I'm using the same config as on the slave servers, but it doesn't work.

```
Host: master.myapp.com
Port: 9999
User: mysql
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you have got?

Comment: PHP PDO returned: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'master.myapp.com' (using password: YES)

Comment: mysql client (mysql -h master.myapp.com) returned: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'master.myapp.com' (111)

Comment: Does master.myapp.com resolve differently on the local machine? Does the address point to the local machine or a port-forwarder? Is there a reason you don't use localhost (filesystem socket)?

Comment: The 2 errors reported above indicate different failure scenarios.

Comment: whops ... I forgot to specify the port when using mysql client from shell. Strangely it connected without asking a password. (mysql -h master.myapp.com -P 9999 -u mysql)

Comment: The first error is that there is something in the triplicate you send (user, host, password) that isn't corresponding, the second is that whatever IP/port master.myapp.com responds to isn't bound to mysql.

Comment: You have multiple `mysql` users then, one without a password probably.

Comment: there is only one `mysql` user (SELECT user FROM mysql.user)

Comment: I changed to localhost but I get this error: `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had ''@'master.myapp.com (anonymous user).
This answer solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/1630391